# CSS Animation Not Working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

This has really been killing me, not sure what the issue is because I have all the -moz- options.

Animation works fine in webkit but not Firefox.

Here's my CSS:

```
    @-webkit-keyframes flip {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
        -o-transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
  }
    to {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}
@keyframes flip {
0% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
        -o-transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
  }
100% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }

}
.jig-loaded img {
  -webkit-animation: flip 1.0s !important;
  animation: flip 1.0s !important; 
   -moz-animation: flip 10.0s !important;
    }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: can you post a fiddle or something? this will be difficult to debug without the relevant HTML, and a fiddle would be very helpful

Comment: You don't seem to have a `@-moz-keyframes` setting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@user3154772: As per my understanding. I have resolve below code.Please check and try it.  
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
        -o-transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
  }
    to {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes flip {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
        -o-transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
  }
    to {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}
@keyframes flip {
0% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
        -o-transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
  }
100% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }

}
.jig-loaded img {
  -webkit-animation: flip 1.0s !important;
  animation: flip 1.0s !important; 
   -moz-animation: flip 10.0s !important;
    }
```

Comment: this appears to be identical the the code in the question ... please highlight what you have changed

Comment: I have added this line extra...Actually it will work for Mozilla browser.   @-moz-keyframes flip {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
        -o-transform: scaleX(0);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
        transform: scaleX(0);
  }
    to {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
}